# How to call function which construct in class and want to call that function in same class and store return value in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am newbie in python OOPs programming. I stuck in one problem.
I want to make class. I tried to write function in class. Now I want to call function in same class and want to store return value in variable within class.

Example:

```
class extract_user_profile(object):

    #ukNames = []

    def __init__(self,data,pdf_to_text_list,text_prop_dict,text_dict):

        self.data = data
        self.pdf_to_text_list = pdf_to_text_list
        self.text_prop_dict = text_prop_dict
        self.text_dict = text_dict

    def read_csv(input_file):
        file = open(input_file, 'r')
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        return reader

    def person_name_list(self,dir_path):
        file_name = 'uknames.csv'
        reader = self.read_csv(dir_path + file_name)
        name_list = []
        for row in reader:
            name_list.append(row[0].lower())
        return name_list
    dir_path = "/Users/imac086/Documents/premal/projects_Quix/CV_parsing/ResumeParser-master/"


    u = person_name_list(dir_path) # I want to call person_name_list function in class

    def getName():
        for i in u: # I want to use u variable which I get from above. and this is in to the class
           print(u)
```

here I created two function in class now I want to call `person_name_list` function within class and store return value in variable within class. Like below I tried without class.

```
u = person_name_list(dir_path)
```

so here `u` variable have contain return value of person_name_list. those values I want to use in remaining functions.

I tired to use and call function like

```
u = self.person_name_list(self,dir_path)
```

I wrote self because I call read_csv file in that function also. it gives me error below:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

So How can I do that? Please let me know. If I make any mistake in question please forgive me.

Comment: HI, Can you please send me link of Question which asked before? Because I tried but I was not able to find it

Comment: Look at the very top of your question.

Comment: Also see the [docs on methods](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects). One excerpt: *"the special thing about methods is that the instance object is passed as the first argument of the function"*